# Converting MPH to minute miles

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm attempting to convert MPH into minute miles. I'm currently running code to do this by doing 60 / the miles per hour which gives me the result in minute miles.

For example 60/8mph = 7.5

However the answer I get I need to convert into minutes and seconds so that I would have 7 minutes 30 seconds. Is there a way I can get the numbers after the decimal point so I can multiply it by 60 to convert it to seconds, then add it back to the minutes.

Comment: Something like `value % 1.0 * 60.0` minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use remainder,

```
double remainder = fmod(a_double, another_double);
```

should include `<math.h>`

Comment: You asking.. "Is there a way I can get the numbers after the decimal point" so it's remainder.... and in objective-c you can get remainder as I explain here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know whether there is an existing class that handles this, but to answer your specific question, the fractional part of the decimal (mantissa?) would be:

`((60 % 8) / 8.0f)`

You can multiply that by 60.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in seconds...

```
3600/8  = 450 
450/60  =  7 remainder 30   

=  7:30
```

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty simple, you're on the right path actually.

What you need to do is:

1. Get Minutes
2. Get Seconds
3. Convert seconds from int to real time (0.5 to 30, etc..)
4. Add seconds to minutes

**Get minutes by casting it to an Integer:**

`int minutes = 60/8;`

**Get seconds by using the remainder:**

`float seconds = 60%8;`

**Convert seconds to real time:**

`int realSeconds = seconds * 60;`

**Now get result back by adding both:**

`int totalSeconds = minuts + realSeconds;`

Here's a little function that does it (typed directly to browser, probably won't compile)

```
#include <math.h>

int getMinuteMiles(float mph){

    int minutes = 60/mph;
    double seconds = fmod(60, mph);
    int realSeconds = seconds * 60;

    return minutes+realSeconds;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong in several ways. You don't use the `mph` parameter of your little function. The OP want a separate minutes value and a separate seconds value. This doesn't do that. You have a needless cast, you use the wrong data type for `seconds` and the math is simply wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I updated the answer, I think the OP didn't ask for separate minutes and seconds, He asked how can he obtain the remainder alone in order to convert it to seconds and add it back to mins. which is what I did :), but I didn't get the part on why the math is wrong ?